# Constructor is not getting called

Tags: php

I have a strange problem with one of my classes.

The class is the next one

```
namespace Core;
class RequestHandler{
    protected $app;
    public function RequestHandler($app){
        echo "EEE";
        $this->app = $app;
    }
}
```

And the initialization is

```
$requestHandler = new Core\RequestHandler($app);
```

I don't know why it doesn't show anything, but if I change the constructor to **__construct** everything works fine.

I'm using php 5.6.20 and I know that it should execute the constructor by name too.

Comment: The problem seems to be the namespace; I'm not sure if the "old style constructor" name has to be a fully-qualified namespaced name, except that you can't use a "\" in a method name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

```
<?php
namespace Foo;
class Bar {
    public function Bar() {
        // treated as constructor in PHP 5.3.0-5.3.2
        // treated as regular method as of PHP 5.3.3
    }
}
?>
```

> Warning
>
> Old style constructors are DEPRECATED in PHP 7.0, and will be removed in a future version. **You should always use __construct() in new code.**

So in *5.6.20* constructor by name is not deprecated.

> As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. **This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.**

You may try to remove namespace, but I don't think it's good way to solve it.

Comment: Thank you, I will change it to __construct, that is the best solution.